# IllegalMonitorStateException Xamarin (Android)

Tags: c#, исключения, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Часть Activity:

```
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Redo).Click += delegate
{
    DrawThread.Running = true;
    new Thread(DrawView.drawThread.Run).Start(Mode);
};
```

DrawView.drawThread.Run:

```
 public async void Run(object data)
    {
        var mode = (bool) data;
        var canvas = _surfaceHolder.LockCanvas();
        try
        {     
         //Drawing logic 
         //Bla bla bla
         await Task.Factory.StartNew(Draw);  
        }
        finally
        {
            canvas.DrawBitmap(BitmapForSaving, 0, 0, null);
            try
            {
                _surfaceHolder.UnlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                //Здесь в visual studio необработанное исключение
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error("", e.ToString());
                /*вывод
                Java.Lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.IllegalMonitorStateException' was thrown.
                08-02 11:05:27.293 E/        ( 3087):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
                08-02 11:05:27.293 E/        ( 3087):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
                08-02 11:05:27.293 E/        ( 3087):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
                08-02 11:05:27.293 E/        ( 3087):   at Android.Views.ISurfaceHolderInvoker.UnlockCanvasAndPost (Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas) [0x0005a] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
                08-02 11:05:27.293 E/        ( 3087):   at RWP.DrawThread+<Run>d__16.MoveNext () [0x002f4] in C:\Users\coopjmz\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\RWP\RWP\DrawThread.cs:71 
                08-02 11:05:27.293 E/        ( 3087):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalMonitorStateException stack trace ---
                08-02 11:05:27.293 E/        ( 3087): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
                08-02 11:05:27.293 E/        ( 3087):   at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:126)
                08-02 11:05:27.293 E/        ( 3087):   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1260)
                08-02 11:05:27.293 E/        ( 3087):   at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:434)
                08-02 11:05:27.293 E/        ( 3087):   at android.view.SurfaceView$4.unlockCanvasAndPost(SurfaceView.java:1015)

            */
            }
            Running = false;
        }
    }
```

Почему так происходит и что с этим делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, ты вызываешь `var canvas = _surfaceHolder.LockCanvas();` в одном потоке, а `_surfaceHolder.UnlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);` в другом, теряя контекст. Например, из-за использования `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Убедиться в этом ты можешь в отладчике.

Владельцем блокировки выступает первый поток, а освободить пытается другой из-за чего и возникает подобное исключение.

Если ты попробуешь написать более тривиальный пример:

```
lock (_obj)
{
  await Task.Run(()=>{});
}
```

То получишь ошибку ещё на этапе компиляции:

> cannot await in the body of a lock statement

Это как раз защита от подобных ошибок и потенциальных дедлоков.

Comment: Может ли проблема заключаться в том, что рисование на canvas происходит в другом потоке?

Comment: Да, ты прав, спасибо за ответ. Попытаюсь решить проблему самостоятельно, но, если что - буду обращаться ))

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId меняется после вызова await Task.Factory.StartNew(Draw), как это можно исправить? Через Async.SwitchToContext? Он же только в F# есть.